# Laravel 10: The validate not Work with all fields

Tags: laravel, validation

I have the next problem, I need some help.

I have a simple form:

```
@if (session('error'))
<div class="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 alert alert-danger">
{{ session('error') }}
</div>
@endif
@error('nombre')
<div class="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 alert alert-danger">
{{ $message }}
</div>
@enderror
 <form  method="POST" action="{{ route('user') }}">
  @csrf

  <input type="text" name="nombre">
  <input type="text" name="alias" >
  <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-primary my-2" />
</form>
```

Then in the controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\UserModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


public function store(Request $request):Request
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'=>'nullable|required',
            'alias'=>'nullable|required'
         ]);

        $usuario = new UsuariosModel;
        $usuario->name= $request->name;
        $usuario->alias = $request->alias;
        $usuario->save();

        return redirect()->route('usuarios')->with('success','Usuario creado correctamente.');
    }
```

And the Route:

```
Route::post('/user', [UserController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth')->name('user');
```

If I delete the validation, the Insert works fine, name is validated successful, but alias not.

If I only put             `'alias'=>'nullable|required'`, it don't work any way.

I can't find the error in this simple form.

Comment: Why is the validation checking for `name` and `alias`, but the inputs clearly have `nombre` and `alias` to the `name=` attributes?

Comment: I translate (wrong) this post, but in the originals all are nombre and alias. And the insert is fine on mysql (if I delete the validate).

Comment: i think there is contradictory about your validation, `'alias'=>'nullable|required'` what do you mean? nullable but you also take required, it's doesn't work. if you don't fill the alias input, the validation execute `required` even though you add `nullable`. so you must delete one of them `nullable` or `required`

Answer (score 0):

Blade form

```
<form  method="POST" action="{{ route('user') }}">
  @csrf

  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="alias" >
  <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-primary my-2" />
</form>
```

UsuariosModel

```
class UsuariosModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'alias ',
    ];
}
```

Controller

```
   public function store(StoreRequest $request):Request
    {
        $usuario = UsuariosModel::create($request->validated());

        return redirect()->route('usuarios')->with('success','Usuario creado correctamente.');
    }
```

And Noew create Store Request using artisan

```
php artisan make:request StoreRequest
```

and change authorize return to true

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'alias' => 'required|string',
        ];
    }
}
```

And there's no error if you use nullable just remove nullable